# ggplot + dplyr not stacking data correctly or removing data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom-bar

I'm trying to a stacked bar graph, and for some reason my bars are not stacking correctly. [The stacks are out of order and the colors consolidated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMKZo.png) I'm not really sure how to fix the problem

```
g12<-terror %>% 
group_by(attacktype1_txt,iyear,nkillter) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=iyear,y=nkillter,fill=attacktype1_txt)) +
geom_bar(stat='identity',position='stack')  + xlab('Year of Attack') + 
ylab('Number of Deaths')
g12=g12+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Attack Types"))
g12
```

[or when I try and use the summarise function to make the bars stack correctly I get this oddity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwmKY.png)

```
g12<-terror %>% 
group_by(attacktype1_txt,iyear,nkillter) %>% summarise(number=n()) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=iyear,y=nkillter,fill=attacktype1_txt)) +
geom_bar(stat='identity',position='stack')  + xlab('Year of Attack') + 
ylab('Number of Deaths')
g12=g12+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Attack Types"))
g12
```

This results in this a graph that is correctly stacked, but as you can see by comparing the two that it has thrown out a lot of the data. Is there some function I could use that will still consolidate the data without throwing out data like summarise seems to be?

Comment: You need to provide us with some data to try and recreate your problem.

Comment: This is the dataset

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzgRASyCPi42RDdKY25adVZoWFk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first piece of code works. Granted, you can simplify it:

```
ggplot(terror, aes(iyear, nkillter)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = attacktype1_txt), stat = "identity") +
    xlab('Year of Attack') + ylab('Number of Deaths') + 
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Attack Types"))
```

[image]

But this seems to be a correct representation of the data, if I understand it correctly. Just to check ourselves, lets check 2015:

```
> (terror %>% select(iyear, attacktype1_txt, nkillter) %>% 
              arrange(attacktype1_txt, nkillter) %>%
              filter(iyear==2015, nkillter > 0))
       iyear                     attacktype1_txt nkillter
    1   2015                       Armed Assault        1
    2   2015                       Armed Assault        1
    3   2015                       Armed Assault        1
    4   2015                       Armed Assault        1
    5   2015                       Armed Assault        1
    6   2015                       Armed Assault        2
    7   2015                   Bombing/Explosion        1
    8   2015                   Bombing/Explosion        1
    9   2015                   Bombing/Explosion        1
    10  2015                   Bombing/Explosion        1
    11  2015                   Bombing/Explosion        2
    12  2015 Hostage Taking (Barricade Incident)        1
    13  2015 Hostage Taking (Barricade Incident)        2
    14  2015         Hostage Taking (Kidnapping)        3
```

As depicted in the plot, we have 7 armed assault deaths, 6 bombing/explosion, 3 barricade and 3 kidnappings.

Comment: This is really strange. The exact same code leads to this graph output 
http://i.imgur.com/wHUIhjR.png

Comment: hmm.. what version of ggplot are you running?